# ORA-02291: parent key not found when inserting multiple rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, dblink, ora-02291

I having a problem executing an stored procedure that does multiple inserts

I am a copying 30 tables from a instance of a server to another by a DBLINK:

```
INSERT INTO table@dblink (column1)
         SELECT column1
         FROM table;
```

But it results in:

> ORA-02291:    integrity constraint (string.string) violated - parent key not found

There is only one commit at the end of the procedure.

The 4th table that I'm inserting, has an FK to the first one, and its no recognizing the inserts of the first one (I have tried with deferred constraints and same problem: ORA-02291).

Comment: do you copy in a correct order?  first tables without foreign keys and then with some

Comment: Yes i do. This is just a part of a big package that worked a lot of times. Now we are increasing the size of the data that we need to copy and we find that error. The order is correct.

Comment: did you try to do a commit after each table?

Comment: I can't, business rules... the procedure must copy all or nothing. (Doing a commit after each table it works, i try it in another server just to test, but the procedure must not do that).

Comment: Since we do not see the data and the merge procedure, it's not easy to tell where the problem is.
The error message already says that no parent record can be found. Select the table and check if there really are no records for which no parent record exists. Maybe the FK is disabled on the source database or there are any conditions that filter the data when replicating?

Comment: Its exactly the same database, same constraints. If i do the same insert in a pl sql sheet one by one, there is no problem. The errors appears when i execute the procedure, there is no data's problem, i checked everything about the data and constraints.

Comment: If you say the problem is is in the procedure and you do not show us the procedure, how can we help you? you should provide more information

Comment: I understand, but i am not allow to copy that procedure here. There is no extra logic, that procedure a 30 insert into in the correct order. Nothing more than that, thats why i am asking here, im dissapointed, i tried everything.

Comment: You don’t have to share your actual code, just a demo that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are modifying data (DML) through db-link. This might be ill-managed by Oracle, and cause unexpected behavior. You should do it the other way around: instead of pushing data, drag data through this db-link, and do the inserts locally. Of course, you probably cannot *technically* do what you want on the destination database...

The solution you have is to deactivate the FK before your inserts, then activate the FK.

However, I am not sure this DDL is possible directly through db-link... You may need to create a procedure to deactivate the FKs on the destination database, and call it via db-link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a great idea. I created two procedures, one to disable constraints before the inserts and another to enable the constraints. I executed, and it gives me the same error. 02298 keys not founded... so strange, its driving me crazy